# Url of static assets not found in development with Vite js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Imports of png images fail to resolve locally (in development mode, running `npm vite`). They do resolve in the production build however. At first I imported them dynamically but they wouldn't resolve in the production build so I imported them beforehand.

```
//.ts file
import test from "../assets/sprites/test.png"
```

```
//vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        target: 'esnext'
    }
})
```

> test.png:1          GET http://localhost:3000/frontend/src/assets/frontend/src/assets/sprites/test.png 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue, use new URL(url, import.meta.url) to resolve static assets both in prod and dev

See Vite documentation on Static Asset Handling : https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url

```
const test = new URL('../assets/sprites/test.png', import.meta.url).href
```

Comment: For me, this works in build but not for dev

Comment: Works in both here. What's your error ?

Comment: Not working for me. Looks like `import ... from 'image.png'` doesn't work in Vite.