# Vite not loading static assets

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vite

Using Vite with Storybook whenever I do something like:

```
import image from '../local-asset.png
```

No error appears but the asset doesn't load.

The only solution found is to create a variable like so:

```
const image = new URL('../local-asset.png', import.meta.url).href
```

My problem is that the main project I work with uses Webpack, instead of Vite, and I am not sure about it's compatibility.

Also, I might be missing the point on why should we go with this more cumbersome solution than just the shorter, simple import we are used to.

A partial answer [was made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210561/url-of-static-assets-not-found-in-development-with-vite-js). I believe this question goes a bit further.

Comment: As of today `@ vite 4.0.0` vite can't still handle assets bundling required in different locations within your css, js, html or otherwise. If you want asset to load it must be imported entry file to bundler